# Tap while scrolling momentum is buggy

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, ios6, touch

I'm using the "new" CSS attribute on iOS to achieve scrolling momentum, `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`. I have a list of `<div>` that you can scroll and select so that the selector vanishes and the selected item is placed elsewhere. The problem is that if the item A is on position (X,Y); I swipe up to scroll down, and while the scrolling momentum is active, I tap again on position (X,Y), where item A used to be, but now occupied by a moving upwards item B, item A is the one being selected.

A video is worth a million words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXh28IY3wIU

Is this a known bug? I am using jQuery's mobile event 'tap' like so:

```
$selector.on('tap', '.act-item-inner', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $selected=$(this);
    [...]
}
```

As you would imagine, $selector is the wrapper and $selected is item B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While scrolling through websites on iOS the browsers

1. takes a screenshot from your site
2. and freezes the JavaScript-Engine (including all JavaScript-/DOM-Events).

So yes, this is known. But it works like designed.
You can observe this behavior by printing some messages to the console via `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. You will see that they are not executed during the elastic scrolling.

I suggest that this leads to a race condition in your particular use case when the engine is unfreezed.